# Ballerina test assertion is not working with xml payload

Tags: xml, assertion, ballerina

I am working on process soap messaged using ballerina. In this i need to write a unit test to assert the response from the back-end axis2 service.

**I tried the following option to do the assertion :**

**1. Tried to convert the soap response to xml and assert with the expected resonse, but seems like ballerina currently doesn't support assertion with xml payloads.**

I tired the following code snippet to try out the assertion.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/test;
import wso2/soap;
import ballerina/http;

endpoint http:Client clientEP {
 url:"http://localhost:9091"
};

@test:Config
function testAssertion() {
 io:println("This function is testing the xml assertion\n");
 xml a1 = xml `<book><name>Sample1</name></book>`;
 xml a2 = xml `<book><name>Sample2</name></book>`;
 test:assertEquals(a1, a2, msg = "Assertion failed");
}
```

Got the following test passing.

```
Compiling tests    seran/consuming_a_soap_service:0.0.1

Running tests
seran/consuming_a_soap_service:0.0.1
This function is testing the xml assertion        
     [pass] testAssertion        
     1 passing        
     0 failing
     0 skipped
```

**2. Tried to convert xml to json and assert**
Top level name spaces are inherited into the child elements which cause the test to fail even though xml payloads in the response and expected response are the same. I am confused with this behavior. I am using the same xml from the response as the expected payload and converting both to json and asserting, but still the test fails.

**3. Tried to iterate over the xml payload and assert only the content.**
this seems to be not a good approach as we aren't asserting the xml format of the response.

How can i proceed with this unit test?

Comment: Can you share the actual payload and the asserted xml?

Comment: You have shown a passing test yourself. Then how can you say that xml assertion is not working?

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed, In above-shared test case, asserted xml values are different but test case is passing. I think that is what Seralathan trying to highlight here.

Comment: ah yes. Then it must be an issue.

Comment: The issue is with the underlying implementation of the test:assertEquals method. In the following implementation https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/master/misc/testerina/modules/testerina-core/src/main/ballerina/test/assert.bal#L49 of assertEquals. reflect:equals(actual,expected) returns true even if the xml payloads are different.

Comment: So seems like the issue is related to core ballerina implementation.